# Polar coordinates: What unit vectors span the $(r,\theta)$ space?

Tags: vectors, electromagnetism

Polar coordinates: What unit vectors span the $(r,\theta)$ space?

I am thoroughly confused. If in the Cartesian system, the associated orthonormal polar vectors at different points on a circle keep changing, then which ones do we choose to span the corresponding $(r, \theta)$ space?

Comment: While Cartesian coordinates are the coefficients of unit vectors $(1,0),(0,1)$ that span $\mathbb R^2$, no such relation holds for polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ corresponding to the Cartesian point $(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$.  In other words $r,\theta$ don't convert to matrix values.  In particular the role of $\theta$ is periodic, and there are other difficulties with trying to use these as linear combinations of spanning vectors.

Comment: But then why do you call them as an orthonormal basis?

Comment: What do you mean by “the $(r,\theta)$ space” to begin with? If you talk about vectors spanning a space, it must be a vector space, but it's not clear to me what vector space you're referring to.

Comment: I mean the space spanned the two orthonormal vectors, r^ and theta^.

Comment: It seems to me your confusion stems from mixing the notions of **vector spaces** (where vectors have coordinates in a particular basis) and **differentiable manifolds** (where points have coordinates in a particular chart). So the term **coordinates** has two different meanings in each case. I'm not sure how to guide you other than tell you "get to know what a vector space and what a manifold is".

Comment: @AI.G. I know a little about vector spaces, done two courses on linear algebra. Where is my lapse in understanding? Where precisely am I mixing the notions of a vector space and a manifold? What is the vector space here that you are talking about?

Comment: What you call "the $(r,\theta)$ space" seems to be the two-dimensional set of points with a non-rectangular coordinate system on it $(r(p),\theta(p))$. It conatains no vectors (it's a set of _points_), so it cannot be "spanned" by vectors in the sense of linear combinations (in which case your question does not really arise). Instead, vectors span _vector spaces_, such as the tangent (vector) spaces to each point of your (p,theta) space.

Comment: For example, you can easily shrink the $(r,\theta)$ space to $r<10$, and it will continue to be a perfectly valid set of points with polar coordinates. But you cannot do that with a vector space, because the resulting subset would no longer be a vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to describe a 2D vector field, e.g., the electric field due to a line charge. In Cartesian coordinates, I'll claim that (up to scalar factors) this would be $$\vec{E}=\frac{x \hat{x}+y\hat{y}}{x^2+y^2}.$$  An advantage of this form is that we may directly differentiate to verify $\nabla\cdot \vec{E}=0$ is true everywhere except the origin origin, where it is ill-defined; this is what we expect of a line charge.

What is not evident from this form is that it has rotational symmetry. If we instead pass to polar coordinates via $(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, the electric field is $$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{r}\Big[(\cos\theta) \hat{x}+(\sin\theta) \hat{y}\Big].$$
This form is manifestly rotationally symmetric: the scalar factor $1/r$ does not depend on $\theta$, and the unit-vector factor rotates so as to always point radially away from the origin. We can therefore think of $\vec{E}$ as having magnitude $1/r$ and pointing radially away from the origin.

More generally, suppose we have some vector field $\vec{F}$ and we choose some point $p=(x,y)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. Then there exist vectors $\hat{r}_p,\hat{\theta}_p$ which are defined as such: If I start at $p$ and increase $r$ slightly, then my point moves radially outward (the $\hat{r}_p$ direction); if I instead increase $\theta$ slightly, my point moves counterclockwise (the $\hat{\theta}_p$ direction). In terms of Cartesian coordinates, we have

\begin{align}
\hat{r}_p &= (\cos\theta)\hat{x}+(\sin\theta)\hat{y},\\
\hat{\theta}_p &= -(\sin\theta)\hat{x}+(\cos\theta)\hat{y},\\
\end{align}

So long as we avoid the origin (where the choice of $\theta$ becomes ambiguous) these vectors are a perfectly respectable orthonormal basis. Hence we can express $\vec{F}$ at $p$ in this (local!) basis: $$\vec{F}(p)=F_r(p)\hat{r}_p+F_\theta(p) \hat{\theta}_p.$$ In particular, the electric field given earlier may be expressed as $$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{r}\hat{r}_p.$$ This formalizes our earlier description of the electric field. So while we now have to put up with a coordinate-dependent basis, our vector field now takes advantage of rotational symmetry. (Moreover, this form is actually the one I secretly started from; indeed, the derivation of this form using Gauss's law is a standard problem in introductory electrodynamics.)

The bottom line is that $\{\hat{r},\hat{\theta}\}$ is a coordinate-dependent orthonormal basis which we (only) use to express $\vec{F}$ at a particular point $p$. (Or, if you like, there's a whole family of such orthonormal bases which are indexed by the point $p$.) In physics, though, it's conventional to write write these as $(\hat{r},\hat\theta)$ and take the coordinate-dependence as implicit. It is also typical to not distinguish between dependence on the point $p$ vs the Cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ or polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$. Thus one will typically see the radial component of the above electric field written as $E_r(r,\theta)=1/r$, ignoring the abuse of notation.

Comment: Can you please give me an example where F_r and F_theta are both non-zero when expressed in polar basis?

But how does this polar basis "HELP" me? What about it is so useful vis-a-vis the cartesian basis? A concrete reason please, not the reason that it makes calculations easier, which seems a posteriori...

Thank you!

Comment: Just one more thing, what aspect of notation is being "abused" in your last line? How would one write the same while being scrupulous, even persnickety, about notation?